# Нужна помощь с bs4,requsts,Tkinter парсер?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, bs4

В чем проблема цикл весь нормально проходит но данные не в строчку ,а в столбик ,не записываютца в графическое окно.Как исправить?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root = Tk()
root.title("G")
root.geometry("800x500")
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}


criptos = "https://ru.investing.com/crypto/currencies"
try:
    def check():
        response = requests.get(criptos, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        quotes = soup.find('table').find('tbody').findAll('tr')
        quo = soup.find('td').findAll('left noWrap elp symb js-currency-symbol')
        quos = soup.find('td').findAll('price js-currency-price')#js-currency-change-24
        quos1 = soup.find('td').findAll('js-currency-change-24')  #js-currency-change-7d
        quos2 = soup.find('td').findAll('js-currency-change-7d')
        for i in range(len(quotes)):
            print(quotes[i].text)

    check()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)


txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=400, height=100)
txt.grid(column=0, row=0)
txt.insert(INSERT, 'Все криптовалюты курс в данный момент:')

root.mainloop()
```

П.с Только начала изучать библиотеку не судите строга.Пробывала через текс парсить также.
Выводит только так

```
Bitpanda Ecosystem Token
BEST
2,51
1,04B $
456,03K $
0%
+0,54%
+24,35%
```

а хотелось вот так :

```
Bitpanda Ecosystem Token==BEST==2,51==1,04B$==456,03K$==0%==+0,54%==+24,35%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного модернизировал ваш скрипт

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import Tk, Text, END
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}


criptos = "https://ru.investing.com/crypto/currencies"

# Декаратор для запуска функции в отдельном потоке
# Что бы не блокировать GUI
def thread(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = Thread(target=function, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()
        return thread
    return wrapper


class Application(Tk):
    data = False
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Парсер цен на крипто валюты")
        self.geometry("800x500")
        self.resizable(width = False, height = False)
    
        self.text = Text(self, width=800, height=500)
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.insert(1.0, 'Все криптовалюты курс в данный момент:\n', END)
    
        self.list_strings = []
    
        self.get_criptos()
        self.is_data()
                
    def __get_response(self):
        try:
            response = requests.get(criptos, headers=headers)
            return response
        except response.ConnectionError as error:
            print(error)
            exit()
    @thread
    def get_criptos(self):
        response = self.__get_response()
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
            quotes = soup.find('table').find('tbody').findAll('tr')
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
            exit()
        for i in range(len(quotes)):
            #print(i)
            new_string = quotes[i].text.replace('\n', ' ')
            self.list_strings.append(f"{new_string}\n")
        print(self.list_strings)
        self.data = True
    
    def is_data(self):
        if self.data:
            print("Данные готовы")
            for i in self.list_strings[::-1]:
                self.text.insert(2.0, f"{i}")
            self.data = False
        self.after(100, self.is_data)

def main():
    application = Application()
    application.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Благодарю , постараюсь запомнить .Честно не знала что так можно.

Comment: У вас не отображалась информация в графическом окне потому что вы её туда не поместили)

Comment: Понятно просто я думала что вывод entry, а по этой функции нечего не было даже в ютубе.Но в документации сказано что она)scrolledtext.ScrolledText )выводит результат, а вот как непонятно.А еще как зделать чтоб не в столбик, а в строчку вывод был?Искала тут и по другим даже кусочки кода пробывала все в столбик парситца.

Comment: В строчку как именно? Приведите в вопросе желаемый результат.

Comment: Добавила в основное сообщение.

Comment: Обновил ответ....

Comment: Благодарю,буду разбиратца и учитца.